# Higher display resolution on Acer 5755g

Tags: nvidia, display, resolution, acer

I am using Acer Aspire 5755g with NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M (2gb) and Ubuntu 13.04. The resolution set by default is 1366x768 and it is the highest possible to choose. I would like to use bigger resolution like 1920x1080 and I believe it is supported by both my video card and my monitor.

Can someone please tell me how to set my resolution to 1920x1080?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native resolution of your monitor is 1366x768, this is a standard value, most 15.6" laptops have this resolution as the highest. Even if you could set it higher, it would not look better, because the monitor is not capable to physically display a higher resolution.

I recommend to use the 1366x768 resolution, however if you still want to try a higher one, you need to create a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file (if you don't have one) and insert a `Modeline` into it. For the 1920x1080 resolution, insert this line into the `Monitor` section:

`Modeline "1920x1080_60.00" 172.80 1920 2040 2248 2576 1080 1081 1084 1118 -HSync +Vsync`

Refer to this page:

http://www.arachnoid.com/modelines/

Comment: Thenk you a lot, but can you please explain to me how to create this `xorg.conf`, will it work if it contains only that line:
`Modeline "1920x1080_60.00" 172.80 1920 2040 2248 2576 1080 1081 1084 1118 -HSync +Vsync`